# Why waitForDuration: method only works once in the update method in sprite kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Here in my code I'm trying to update a label (SKSpriteNode) while the time counts down using sprite kit but I don't want to use NSTimer so I found this solution but the problem is that the waitForDuration method works only the first time update method gets runned. I want to run a block of code (updating a label and a variable) every one second using sprite kit. Any help is appreciated.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    id wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0];
    id run = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        remainingCounts = remainingCounts - 1;
        [progressBar setProgress:remainingCounts/10];
        timerLabelNode.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %d", remainingCounts];

        if (--remainingCounts == 0) {
            _AreYouLost=YES;
            if (_score>[savedBestScore intValue]) {
               [self updateBestScore:[NSMutableString  stringWithFormat:@"%d",_score]];
            }
             [self updateBestScore:[NSMutableString  stringWithFormat:@"%d",_score]];
             SKScene *GameovrScn = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
            GameovrScn.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
            [self.view presentScene:GameovrScn transition:[SKTransition doorwayWithDuration:0.4]];
             NSLog(@"Time is up!!!");
         }
      }];
}
```

Comment: youre making this very complicated by using actions.  the update method is keeping track of time directly.  have you considered just doing your countdown using the time in the update method?

Comment: I would say just move your countdown code to a separate function. You don't need to run it in `update`.

Comment: Ok but where should I call it so it gets called every second? @ChrisSlowik should i call it in update method?

Comment: Do you mean using NSTimer by saying "have you considered just doing your countdown " ? @hamobi

Comment: look at the answer below

Comment: @Reza.Ab The code I can see at the moment of speaking, actually does nothing - you are creating two actions in each update call, but you never run them. SKAction runBlock: method, actually creates an action which executes the block, rather than executing that block directly on call. Another problem with your code is the fact that you are trying to run the block of code each second, but you are doing that inside of a method which runs 60 times per second...Which doesn't really make sense. You should use what trojanfoe pointed, or you can use SKActions...

Comment: I read it and its a well written timer but sorry I still have no clue where to fire up my desired method in "every second" so i can update my labels and scores. @hamobi

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out, i appreciate it :) @Whirlwind

Answer (score 2):

I use similar techniques to throttle things like fire rate, and it works across any game engine that supports frame updates where you can get the *delta time* (i.e. the time between this frame and the last frame).  That's pretty much every game engine I've seen *except* SpriteKit, which gives you the current time (I think it's the time since the game started, but it doesn't matter), so you need to calculate delta time yourself.

You need to use an instance variable to hold the current timer value and decrement *delta time* from that time and when it's `<= 0.0` then it's time to fire it.  If you want it to repeat then reset the countdown.

For example:

```
#define TIMER_VALUE 1.0

@interface MyClass()
{
    CFTimeInterval _lastFrameTime;
    CFTimeInterval _timer;
}
@end

@implementation MyClass()

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _lastFrameTime = 0.0;
        _timer = TIMER_VALUE;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    if (_lastFrameTime == 0.0)           // Might need < DBL_EPSILON here?
        _lastFrameTime = currentTime;    // First frame
    CFTimeInterval deltaTime = currentTime - _lastFrameTime;

    _timer -= deltaTime;
    if (_timer <= 0.0) {
        [self doThing];
        _timer = TIMER_VALUE;
    }

    _lastFrameTime = currentTime;
}
@end
```

Comment: thank you so much, can you just tell me where should i call my desired method to be called in every second? Sorry :( @trojenfoe

Comment: That's the call to `[self doThing];`.

Comment: Ok i'm a little bit confused not, I thought `[self doThing];` is when the time is up?! so where that would be? i mean where can i do this then ---->> `If(timer==0){ do whatever}` and what if i want to add a second whenever the user gets a score? i mean can i do _timer++ in any method i want? @trojanfoe thank you a lot.

Comment: Okay so i gave the initial value to the `_timer = 5.0;` to count down to zero in `initwithSize:` method but it still starts counting down from 0. @trojanfoe

Comment: @Reza.Ab You should unaccept the answer if it doesn't solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it using SKActions:

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@interface GameScene ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) SKLabelNode *label;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger timeLeft;
@end

@implementation GameScene

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

        _timeLeft = 90;
        _label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    }

    return self;
}

//Override timeLeft's setter in order to update label's text property after each assignment to property is made.
-(void)setTimeLeft:(NSUInteger)timeLeft {

    _timeLeft = timeLeft;
    _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Current score %lu", (unsigned long)_timeLeft];

}


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    //How much to wait
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf =  self;

    //What to do
    SKAction *block = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        weakSelf.timeLeft -= 1;
    }];

    //Sequence to repeat - look at this like it represents one step (wait and update what needed)
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, block]];

    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Current score %lu", (unsigned long)self.timeLeft];
    self.label.fontSize = 45;
    self.label.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:self.label];

    //Repeat the step above forever
    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence] withKey:@"countdown"];


}

@end
```

The code is very straight forward (and pretty much commented), but let me explain it once again how it works:

- An action sequence is created once, and reused many times.
- Inside of a block, which is part of that sequence, you update the `timeLeft` variable. This automatically (through overridden setter) updates label's text.
- Sequence is repeated forever.

To stop this action, you can access it through the key, and remove it, like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if ([self actionForKey:@"countdown"]){
        [self removeActionForKey:@"countdown"];
    }

}
```